# How to add settings section on android rom settings?

Tags: android, git, github, settings, rom

I'm creating my Rom from sources, Aosp based, and I have added some features.
But I have a problem with last one. 
My question is: How can I add settings on a setting section already existent or creating new one?
My sources are here -> https://github.com/EF-Aosp
Look for Apps_Settings Repo, the battery customizable commits. I need to show the settings for battery icon customizations. I really need help.

Comment: You might find better help here http://forum.xda-developers.com/

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I know XDA, but I preferred to ask also here ;)